# Apache server settings for Windows WAMP

Tags: apache

I am having hard time for WAMP configuration on Windows 8.1. I've disabled Web Deployement Agent Service in services. Tried every single solution on Stackoverflow but couldn't come to conclusion. My Skype is offline and had switched it to alternate port to get this done which is 443. Please help.

**My httpd.conf file for apache configuration.**

```
ServerName localhost:8080
80HostnameLookups Off

#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080

Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

**My host file**

```
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: Do you get any error message? Read the error log!

Comment: Just that...this page isn't available.